# WooCommerce: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WordPress WooCommerce, enabling either the Min/Max Quantity extension or the Measurement Calculator extension work. But if you enable both, and see the Measurement Calculator to Area the site breaks and shows the following error.

It seems there is an issue with one of the extensions conflicting with the other. From the error is it possible to tell which is the culprit as then I can reach out to that particular extension developer.

Or even better if from the error someone can deduct the issue and solution. Presumably would require hardcoding a temporary fix in one of the plugins but would be helpful until the extension developers fix the conflict.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WC_Min_Max_Quantities::update_quantity_args(), 1 passed in /html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298 and exactly 2 expected in /html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-min-max-quantities/min-max-quantities.php:561 Stack trace: #0 /html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): WC_Min_Max_Quantities->update_quantity_args(Array) #1 /html/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array) #2 /html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-measurement-price-calculator/classes/class-wc-price-calculator-product.php(501): apply_filters('woocommerce_qua...', Array) #3 /Us in /html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-min-max-quantities/min-max-quantities.php on line 561
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to WordPress 4.7.2 which was just released and the error went away. So appears to be a combination of those two plugins being abled with certain settings when using 4.7.1.